# saga code coverage tool runnning only first test case

Tags: angularjs, maven, unit-testing, code-coverage

i am writing test cases for AngularJS code using jasmine and using saga-maven plugin for code coverage .Jasmine runs all the test cases smoothly but on the saga code coverage report it shows that only first test case is covering the code and others do not .whichever test case will be first only that test case covers the code. why is it so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved by replacing the old version angular-mock.js file by new version angular-mock.js file. Now i am using angular-mock_1.3.10.js , it is running all the test cases .